# Retriggerable monostable multivibrator IC down to 500ps

Tags: pulse

I want to generate a fixed 0.5ns 5V electrical pulse where I can modify the repetition rate from 1MHz to 10MHz. Some laser diode drivers or high resolution function generators can achieve this but they are ultra expensive. I couldn't find a pulse shaper which would convert an input to a 0.5ns pulse in the market.

I only could find [this](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1040.pdf) programmable one-shot pulse generator which is down to 5ns.

Am I looking for something that doesn't exist? Other methods I came across to generate such pulse is very difficult in practice for such high bandwidth(handmade analog circuits using programmable unijunction transistor ect).

Is achieving this possible with an FPGA? And if so, what type of FPGA required?(I don't want to start learning FPGA programming if at the end I figure out its not even possible)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a commercial pulse generator? Avtech's AVMR-2D-B or AVMH-1 look like they might meet your needs. (no affiliation, this is just a company I happen to know about that makes this kind of thing.)

Comment: It seems huge in dimensions and probably huge in price. I wanted to find something smaller cheaper which I can embed it inside my enclosure. A 0.5ns one shot pulse shortener. But maybe these devices are the only way, I will read about it. Thank you.

Comment: You can see the price on their website; they're both in the $10k-$12k range. Which I wouldn't consider too expensive as lab equipment goes. But I didn't realize from your question that you wanted something small.

Comment: Actually I wasnt looking for a lab equipment type of thing. More like a unit which can have 5V 1 to 10MHz pulse and output pulses with same freq but 0.5ns duration to drive a laser diode.